# Visual Studio VB: The Operation Could Not Be Completed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I was using Visual Studio 2022 edition and it was working fine last night. When I tried to open it this morning, it gave me an error:

> The operation could not be completed

I don't know what happened. I already have ran into few suggested solutions and nothing seems to work. I have tried:
closing and restarting the Visual Studio;
restarting my computer; and
deleting `.suo`, which I don't have unfortunately. I must also mention that upon closing the error message, I received another message:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Just in case they're connected problem. Any ideas?

Comment: With VS closed, remove the hidden `.vs` folder which is inside the main folder of your Solution. Then, for each Project, delete the content of the `obj` folder. Open the Solution in VS, right-click the Solution in Solution Explorer and clean / rebuilt it (clean may seem redundant at this point, but there's a reason for it)

Comment: @Jimi for your second point, do you mean to clear all the content of the the 'obj' folder? Just to be clear, inside 'obj' folder, there's another folder named 'debug'.

Comment: Yes, manually delete everything that's inside that folder. In all Projects.

Comment: @Jimi ok my only concern now is how to reach my gratitude to you cuz that worked successfully!!! Thank you very much appreciated. As a freshman, that's like life pulled from death. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jimi 's answer from the comments solved this problem.

> With VS closed, remove the hidden .vs folder which is inside the main folder of your Solution. Then, for each Project, delete the content of the obj folder. Open the Solution in VS, right-click the Solution in Solution Explorer and clean / rebuilt it (clean may seem redundant at this point, but there's a reason for it)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (VB programming) I had to go to Extensions->installed in the menu and enable: Web live preview. This seems to become disabled at new update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It might be some type of corruption of files or something. Try reinstalling it to fix the files. Also make sure to turn on sync so your extensions and theme don't get lost.

Comment: appreciated your effort!